# How to get hexadecimal of instruction and distinct value(token) of opcode by ghidra script?

Tags: ghidra, arm, hexadecimal

From disassembled code, I want to extract the hexadecimal of instruction, as boxed in the figure below

[image]

plus, I want to get distinct value of each opcode and its operand,
which means sort of

mov => 1 bl => 57   like thing.

I'm not sure this is the one, but I've found something like this

[image]

in `Ghidra/Processors/ARM/data/manuals/ARM.idx`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume you have an Address object (I'll just use currentAddress) .

With an address you can get the Instruction at that address.  Then read that many bytes from Instruction object.

```
from ghidra.program.flatapi import FlatProgramAPI

api = FlatProgramAPI(currentProgram, monitor)
instruction = api.getInstructionAt(currentAddress)
ibytes = insturction.getBytes()
print(binascii.hexlify(ibytes))
```

You can also inspect the operands with `instruction.getOpObjects()`.  Or look through the GhidraAPI to see what else you do with the operands.  I'm not exactly sure what you are hoping to get out it.

Comment: Awesome! Your answer for hexcode is just what I want!
About opcode and object, the value itself is not important for me,
I just want each opcode/operand to be distinct, no same value, cuz my purpose is to use those as a token for ML
I'll look up `instruction.getOpObjects()` and update if I find what I want!